# Gradient of a function that involves a matrix square root

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, differential, symmetric-matrices

Let $S$ be a positive definite matrix of size $n$.

Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R}_+^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$\forall u \in \mathbb{R}^n, \; f(u) = \text{tr}((\text{diag}(u)S)^{1/2}).$$

What would be its gradient?

Comment: Did you mean $ (u \times \text{diag}(S))^{1/2}$ ?

Comment: No, $\text{diag}(u)$, which is a $n$ by $n$ matrix with $u$ on its diagonal and zeros elsewhere, times $S$.

Answer (score 1):

Given a vector $y$, we'd like to denote two operations: generating a diagonal matrix whose main diagonal is the vector, and the inverse operation of extracting the main diagonal from a matrix into a vector, i.e.
$$Y= {\rm Diag}(y) \implies y={\rm diag}(Y)$$
For this particular function, define the auxiliary variable 
$$X = {\rm Diag}(u)\,S$$
Write the function, and find its differential and gradient as
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= {\rm tr}\big(X^{1/2}\big) \cr
d\phi &= \tfrac{1}{2}X^{-T/2}:dX \cr
 &= \tfrac{1}{2}X^{-T/2}:{\rm Diag}(du)\,S \cr
 &= \tfrac{1}{2}X^{-T/2}S^T:{\rm Diag}(du) \cr
 &= \tfrac{1}{2}SX^{-1/2}:{\rm Diag}(du) \cr
 &= \tfrac{1}{2}{\rm diag}\big(SX^{-1/2}\big):du \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial u} &= \tfrac{1}{2}{\rm diag}\big(SX^{-1/2}\big) \cr
}$$
In several intermediate steps, a colon was used to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm tr}\big(A^TB\big)$$

Comment: Thanks! I don't exactly get why $$ d\phi = \tfrac{1}{2}X^{-1/2}:dX$$ though. Do you use a result about the differential of the matrix square root?

Comment: @PAM You can find this formula in the Matrix Cookbook $$d{\,\rm tr}(f(X))={\rm tr}(f'(X)\,dX)$$ where $f$ is any analytic function and $f'$ is its first derivative. I simply put it in in terms of the trace/Frobenius product for the square root function.

Comment: @PAM That question reminded me that I missed a transpose in my answer, which I just fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but how do you know that the derivative of $X^{1/2}$ is $-\tfrac{1}{2}X^{-1/2}$. This is well-known for the univariate square root, but what about the matrix version?

Comment: @PAM The cookbook formula is for ordinary _scalar_ functions being evaluated for square matrix arguments. It's a straightforward exercise to work it out for a function expanded as a Taylor series.